# How do I get the value from keycode in c#?

Tags: c#

I know i can use `KeysConverter.ConvertToString(value)` to get the keycode from a value, but I can't figure out how to do the opposite (get the value from the keycode). How do I do that?
eg from the string "numPad6" i can get the value 0x66, but how would I get the string if i only have the value?

Comment: You mean turn a string into a keycode?

Comment: Hopefully rewording to clarify OP's understanding.

Answer (score 0):

KeyConverter has a variety of methods to convert to and from. If you mean the literal opposite, convert the string value to a key then it's KeysConverter.ConvertFromString(). You also have ConvertFrom(object) and ConvertTo(object, type).

If there is something else you need to be a bit more specific.